# Email exists function with codeigniter php

Tags: php, database, mysqli, codeigniter-3

I am working forgot password function, on the forgot password page i need check email is already exists on database but am getting problem on email check and it return email not found on database but it actually in the dabatase.

User_model

```
//Email check for forgot password
public function email_exists($email) {

    $sql    = "SELECT username, email FROM users WHERE email = '{$email}' LIMIT 1";
    $result = $this->db->query($sql);
    $row    = $result->row();

    return($result->num_rows() === 1 && $row->email) ? $row->username : false;

}
```

Controller

```
public function forgot_password() {

    if(isset($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['email'])) {

        // Load form helper and validation library
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email Address', 'trim|required|valid_email');

        if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {

            //Email not valid, return to forgot password page and show error
            $data['title'] = 'Forgot password';

            $this->load->view('header', $data);
            $this->load->view('forgot_password', array('error' => 'Enter a valid email address.'));
            $this->load->view('footer');

        } else {

            $email  = trim($this->input->post('email'));
            $result = $this->user_model->email_exists($email);

            if($result) {
                $this->send_password_to_email($email, $result); //send_password_to_email
                $this->load->view('header');
                $this->load->view('forgot_password_ok', array('email' => $email));
                $this->load->view('footer');

            } else {

                $data['title'] = 'Forgot password';

                $this->load->view('header', $data);
                $this->load->view('forgot_password', array('error' => 'Email address is not found on our database.'));
                $this->load->view('footer');
            }

        }
    } else {

        $data['title'] = 'Forgot password';

        $this->load->view('header', $data);
        $this->load->view('forgot_password');
        $this->load->view('footer');

    }

}
```

Please help me to fix this. Let me know if you need more detail

Comment: first of all check r u getting email value? `echo $this->input->post('email');` or `print_r($_POST);`

Comment: @devpro i used to echo input value and hit submit it showing the value what i entered.

Comment: than use `return ($result->num_rows() === 1) ? true : false;`

Comment: or `return ($result->num_rows() > 0) ? true : false;`

Comment: @devpro no luck same error message

Comment: or if u want username for `send_password_to_email` function than try `if(!empty($result)) {`

Comment: ok, in your model, debug following: `print_r($row);`

Comment: also test your query in phpmyadmin `SELECT username, email 
FROM users WHERE email = 'yourEmail' LIMIT 1`

Comment: @devpro you mean in the controller ? i was tried this too

Comment: no, first of all check your query in phpmyadmin manual, and than test in your user model. `print_r($row);`

Comment: I got success by your idea. used: `return ($result->num_rows() > 0) ? true : false;` and `if(!empty($result)) {` same time. thank you so much @devpro

Comment: good, i am converting it into an answer...than u can accept this.

Comment: but before posting the answer check one more thing... `var_dump($result);exit;` before `if(!empty($result)) {` line

Comment: var_dump for what?

Comment: Just chk result is true or false

Comment: Its working, shown true if the value is in db if not showing false. like `boolean true` and `boolean false`

Comment: Answer uploaded friend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your model function body as:

```
public function email_exists($email) {

    $sql = "SELECT username, email FROM users WHERE email = '{$email}' LIMIT 1";
    $result = $this->db->query($sql);
    $row = $result->row();

    return $result->num_rows() > 0 ? true : false;
}
```

I am changing this line:

```
return $result->num_rows() > 0 ? true : false;
```